# Prove $X = (\vec{x_1},...,\vec{x_n})^T$, then $X^T X = \sum \vec{x_i} \vec{x_i}^T$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

How would I prove the above identity - I don't want to write out each component and do the multiplication. Is there any other way?

Comment: Would index notation (einstein-style) be okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X^TX = (\vec x_1,\ldots,\vec x_n)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c} \vec x_1^T\\\ldots \\ \vec x_n^T\end{array}\right) = \vec x_1\vec x_1^T +\ldots + \vec x_n \vec x_n^T$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Given the standard basis vectors $\e_k\in\bbR n$
and a matrix whose column vectors are $\,a_k\in\bbR m$

we can expand the matrix as a sum of vector pairs
$$\eqalign{
A \;=\; \m{a_1&a_2&\ldots&a_n}
  \;=\; \LR{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\,\e_i^T} 
  \in\, \bbR{m\times n} \\
}$$
This expansion can be used to calculate the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) of $A$
$$\eqalign{
A^TA
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (\e_i a_i^T)\,(a_j\e_j^T) 
 \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_i^Ta_j)\,(\e_i\e_j^T) \\
 &= \m{
 a_1^Ta_1&a_1^Ta_2&\ldots&a_1^Ta_n \\
 a_2^Ta_1&a_2^Ta_2&\ldots&a_2^Ta_n \\
 \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
 a_n^Ta_1&a_n^Ta_2&\ldots&a_n^Ta_n \\
} \\
}$$
and the Gram matrix of $A^T$ as
$$\eqalign{
AA^T
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_i\e_i^T)\,(\e_ja_j^T) \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_i \,\delta_{ij}\, a_j^T \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i a_i^T \\
}$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) symbol.